# Can i change the location of page table to another NUMA node?

Tags: memory, operating-system, kernel, numa, page-tables

Hi i'm studying memory management of linux kernel.

My machine has multiple NUMA nodes, and i wonder if i can change the location of page table from NUMA 0 to NUMA N.
I studied that, at the page table initialization, CR3 register has pointer to where the page table will be initialized. And the location is on NUMA 0(first NUMA node)'s memory(kernel space).

So at the initialization, can i set the placement of page table to NUMA N?

If possible, kernel modification is all i supposed to do or more works are have to be done?

I'm using x86_64 processor and centos 7.7

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Mitosis. https://github.com/mitosis-project/mitosis-linux. They replicate the page table across the NUMA nodes so you don't need to move it anywhere. Also it is hard to move page tables as they use physical address-based pointers.